# Filegroup design for Document Table for BLOB Storage

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table for storing documents as VARBINARY types in my database (I'm not using filestream). My database is setup with only one data file, but I am wondering if there is a benefit to creating a secondary data file/filegroup and moving that table to the new filegroup. Would this provide any speed or efficency benefit for the database? I'm not looking to secondary move the files to a separate disk, so I know that wouldn't benefit me in that area.

Also I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.